# Passing a reference of current object to parent constructor

Tags: java

My constructor looks like this:

```
public MainApplet() {
   super(new TitansArena(), false);
}
```

I want to be able to pass a reference of my MainApplet object to TitansArena constructor, how can I do that?

Comment: Yes, but that will not be compiled by java :D

Comment: Do not do that in the `MainApplet` constructor, it is bad practice (and has a name, constructor leakage)

Comment: you mean the mainapplet reference to titansarea or another reference to mainapplet and to titansarea?

Comment: I want to access MainApplet from inside TitansArena.

Comment: The title of this question bears no resemblance to the code contained in it. They're basically contradicting one another.

Comment: Sorry, i am a little tired so my english skills are tired too, i've spent the last 4 hours trying to find a solution for this :D

Comment: well everyone on their toes to downvote 2 sec 2 down whow,sorry romeo

Comment: Nothing should ever need a reference to `MainApplet` if it's your class that extends `Applet`, really.

Comment: Let's take a step back here. What technical problem are you having that you think asking this question will solve? That is, *why* are you doing this in the first place? This is [generally a very bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851813/java-leaking-this-in-constructor). And I see no *good* reasons for why your classes should need to hold a reference to `Applet` or your derivatives of it.

Comment: You have to create one object, then the other.  You can't pass `this` until after the super line, in fact it is allowed but often a bad idea to pass it anywhere in the constructor.

Comment: What about a JSObject.getWindow(); which i have and (needs to stay there) in TitansArena?

Comment: ok romeo look at this post please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717953/passing-reference-of-class-to-another-class

Comment: @Romeo: Well, since we don't know what `TitansArena` represents, we can't say for sure. What conceptually does `TitansArena` represent?

Comment: I am sorry guys for wasting your time. I have found a way around it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737141/keep-reference-to-new-object-passed-into-super-constructor?rq=1 Thank you all :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a way 'around' the problem like this:

```
public class MainApplet extends LwjglApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    TitansArena game;
    public MainApplet() {
        this(new TitansArena());
    }

    private MainApplet(TitansArena ta) {
        super(ta, false);
        game = ta;
        game.ap = this; 
    }
}
```

Where `ap` is declared like this: `public Applet ap;` in `TitansArena`.

Comment: this is creepy, why you want you store in an atribute field a reference of itself, and why if you pass super(ta,false) then you game = ta ; no sense..

Comment: I need the to create a `JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow();` Inside TitansArena class. In order to do this i need a reference to applet so this is why I keep a reference to my applet in `game.ta` . It actually has a sense.

Comment: Really not .. it's circular.. to obtain your TitansArea is inside your applet class .. think about it

Comment: SO how can you create a `JSObject` inside TitansArena? The constructor needs an `Applet` argument.